# ASP.NET work not stable in IE

Tags: asp.net, session

I am building an ASP.NET web application use ajax to request some content and it works well in FireFox, Chrome but in IE not stable:
When use login he/she can view owner files, if not login page return string "no permission".

I logined website, I refresh page in IE sometime it show file and sometime it show "no permission" (that not login) I refresh again it show file. I mean that some request it works correct and some request it works wrong! I have seen HTTP request and see that all cookie sent correct.

Here one request

> POST http://abc.com/xxx.asmx/GetFileInfo HTTP/1.1 
>   x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest 
>  Accept-Language: en-us 
>   Referer: http://abc.com/?work=home 
>  Accept: application/json,
>   text/javascript, */*; q=0.01 
>  Content-Type: application/json;
>   charset=utf-8 
>  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
>  User-Agent:
>   Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0;
>   SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729;
>   Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) 
>  Host: abc.com 
>   Content-Length: 27 
>  Connection: Keep-Alive 
>  Pragma: no-cache
>   
>  Cookie:
>   __utma=63255935.688817123.1357236998.1357236998.1357390216.2; __utmb=63255935.5.10.1357390216; __utmz=63255935.1357236998.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); .ASPXAUTH=E83DCA879A8A9AF5DAE72854241CFEBF2AF4BCE7E2227465E71FB428D6816C555176F9F1A1E94CB34F9C48C4FC7C64FBCAA013672182720254821F802242B90098A01A727AA30D4A621B921536B0F5E36F9DE9382972CE7AFC52EA819669E8B8F7D4C5ECCA1EDE07D971CEA64E5847BBC0E9ACB7B26F07BC769422B8C68A5F04F2B183533C95CC6849A8B98D83F22BC306FF564FE8519A1738AC8DB1F4C55A5B6E84FC02D863C22AF3CBD04E70186C497A240313C107DD74B3D28F2AE6BF95FED3E6EA2CC7EE1767F9E9FCBD5A6EEF77EF61198BD65342E6C10B978595DADA17FBDC83A2;
>   ASP.NET_SessionId=ibxe0t55thibhb45vcgkxmvx; __utmc=63255935  
>   
>  {'ID1':'13','ID2':'2'}

How I fix it? 
Thank you!

Comment: try on web.confi to disable the cacheRolesInCookie as `<roleManager cacheRolesInCookie="false"` - also delete your cookies from IE, and try again.

Comment: My web.config has <roleManager enabled="false"> and I not save role in cookie, I just save ID of user.

Answer (score 0):

I know why, because I not set Machine Key in web.config file.